# json-rpc parameters version 1.0 vs 2.0

Tags: json-rpc

Can I have a request on json-rpc 1.0 with parameters like that:

```
{...,"params":[{"name":"x","type":"y"}],...}
```

or this is possible only in 2.0 version?

I try more examples,but don't works.I send parameters only as a list

```
{....,"parmas":["name","type"],.....}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You CAN have object parameters in 1.0, inside the array, so your first example is correct.

The difference is that in 1.0 there must be an array in params (that can contain objects), and in 2.0 params itself can be an object.

Correct in both 1.0 and 2.0:

```
params: [{ "key": "value" }, "Other param" ]
```

Correct in 2.0, but NOT 1.0:

```
params: { "key": "value", "other": "param" }
```

Comment: Note that 1.0 specification says that params is "an array of object".  As such, my first example would be invalid, containing a string in the array.  But, I think it is just a bad choice of words in the specification and not the intent to disallow non-object parameters.

Answer (score 2):

1.0 only supports an array of parameters.

- [JSON-RPC 1.0 specification](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification_v1#a1.1Requestmethodinvocation)

2.0 added support for named parameters.

- [JSON-RPC 2.0 specification](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#request_object)